# LinqToSql: multiple entity namespaces

Tags: linq-to-sql

Has anyone figured out a way to have more than one entity namespace within a single dbml?

Different parts of my database are related to different things and I have them organized into different schemas.  It would be handy if the schemas would translate to namespaces on the generated entities.

There is no way to do this as far as I found.  The best I've come up with is to have multiple dbmls, but that has too much duplication for my liking.

Can Linq to Entities do this?  If so I'd consider switching.

I don't want to use NHibernate until it gets real linq support in version 2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get any answers on this, so I'll answer it myself.

There is NOT any way to have multiple namespaces in a single linq2sql dbml file as far as I have been able to discover.